# USB for charging and data transfer

Tags: microcontroller, usb, charging

I would like to design a system where when my device is connected to a USB cable for charging, it should stop the device from functioning and charge the device. The device should be non-functional while connected to USB cable for charging. Also, I would like to transfer data over USB from the same device.

It is a battery-operated device and the USB class is USB CDC i.e. data transferred is not something that is previously stored somewhere e.g. SD card or some storage location.
How to make something similar work?

Turning Off the device can be easily done by taking input from VBUS and attaching interrupt on it and reading it on micro-controller.

There is a case where the device won't be able to know if the device is plugged in for charging or data transfer. I am thinking of something like starting a timer when an interrupt is generated on the USB cable and if no data transfer interrupts over USB is generated within some time, make a device non-functional.

Is there some different approach I can try?

Comment: Why is it important that these functions be distinct?   Your timer idea isn't crazy, but consider the failure modes, eg, you have power but the host OS isn't enumerating you, then after seconds/minutes/hours suddenly it does.  That's why its important to be specific about *why* you want the modes to be non-overlapping, eg, what happens if you thought you were charge only and you suddenly get enumerated?   Also, presumably you're assuming no one enforces the 100 mA pre-enumeration limit; or are you detecting specific charger schemes on the data lines???

Comment: Those are the only two things your device can know - i.e. is there VBUS connected, and is USB enumerated. If there is no VBUS there is also won't be a data link. If there is a data link, there must be VBUS too.

Comment: @Justme well there are the variety of non-standard (and later, different somewhat standard) schemes that phones and similar devices use to detect that they are getting power form their vendor unique (or compatible) chargers, rather than USB hosts.  But the key problematic word there is "variety"...  And they tend to fall back to drawing 500 mA if they don't decide the source is a charger, regardless if they do or do not get immediately/later/never enumerated...

Comment: If the device shouldn't be operational while charging, you need some means to tell it that it should charge, such as a switch that the user can flip. Or use different cables, one for charging and one for data.